# jupyter is not runing even after installation

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science

jupyter is install but still it shows this

```
> jupyter notebook
jupyter : The term 'jupyter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
```

- jupyter notebook
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (jupyter:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: Into what directory was jupyter installed?  Did you add that directory to your `PATH` environment?

Comment: Based on the error, jupyter did not get installed completely to your PATH

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using windows, Jupyter can be opened via your start menu and will open in a chrome tab.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).